# Pin a tile (App or shortcut) to a specified position on Startscreen (Windows 8 / Powershell)

Tags: windows-8, powershell, modern-ui, vbscript, windows-8.1

The title is nearly the whole question.

I am searching a solution to **pin an installed app or desktop application to the windows 8 startscreen**.

I am in an **enterprise environment** and the purpose is to add a new tile to the startscreen if some new software was delivered to the user. But with the **speciality to pin this new tile to a specific position**. F.e. we have three groups (Desktop/Apps/Office) now the user gets a new App, there should be a way to add a new tile to the "Apps" Group on the first position.

The best solution will be a powershell or if there is no other possibility a batch/vbs to do this. I also tried the new powershell cmdlets (f.e. `Export-StartLayout -as xml`) searched the technet to solve this problem but with absolutly no success.

Comment: there is no automatic way. customize the screen this way: http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2012/10/26/start-screen-customization-with-mdt.aspx

Comment: There must be a way. F.e. Flexera Studio can do this and I think M$ must provide a way especially for the Enterprise Environment - I hope

Comment: Flexera can put the icon exactly where they want for both existing and new users / profiles?

Comment: the layout is stored in this file: "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms", maybe they decoded the file format, but I haven't found a documentation about it.

Comment: Yes I found the file(s) too. With no documentation from MS or other Websites. @AthomSfere - Yes it could but only on Win 8.0 not 8.1 :( possibly MS changed the way to do this